# Can you make custom html libraries and/or modules?

Tags: html

When I was learning to program C in College, I learned about making custom libraries and modules that I can use to store my own functions and call them where and when I need them.  Is there someway to do that with html that I can then link to my main page?  Something like this?  I didn't see a tutorial or anything online, so I wasn't sure.

```
// myLibrary.lib - name of file

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     function function1(){
        *code*
     }
</script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     function function2(){
        *code*
     }
</script>

<script language="html" type="text">
     function function3(){
        <h1>Hello!</h1>
        <p>\nHello there!</p>
     }
</script>
```

Then when I need call a function, I can just call myLibrary.functionX().

Is this possible?

Comment: Check JavaScript module/library pattern : https://medium.freecodecamp.com/javascript-modules-a-beginner-s-guide-783f7d7a5fcc#.kkz9gkv66

Comment: With pure HTML? No. Otherwise, please select a server-side environment (e.g. Ruby on Rails, PHP, Node.js, etc.)

Comment: OP, if you can confirm that your question is about whether this is possible with pure HTML, Jonathon can post that as an answer.

Comment: `<script language="html">` is not a thing.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart  I'm trying to do it outside of the server-side environment, but I'll try.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev  That was just an example.  One of my functions I would like to do is to create a header function and footer function so that I won't have to keep writing the header and footer over and over again with every webpage.  I can simply type HeaderFunction() or whatever and it will automatically add in a header.  (Obviously it's more detailed than that.)

Comment: @BSMP  It doesn't have to be pure HTML.  It can use Javascript, CSS, whatever.  I just want to know if it's possible and how to go about doing it.

Answer (score 2):

HTML is not a programming language. You cannot create an HTML function of any kind. However, you definitely can do what you are asking about with javascript. Just write a javascript file using your favorite text editor, then link it to your html file.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that HTML is not a programming language.  That wasn't what I was asking.  I'll look into figuring out how to make a javascript library file.

Comment: The closest thing to a HTML "function" I suppose would be a separate html file that you call inside an iframe. BTW, please accept this answer if it solves your question, at least as well as it can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

For Javascript, I would use [Node Package Manager](https://www.npmjs.com/) for this purpose, although it involves quite a number of steps.

Let's create a simple library. We define two functions and export them by assigning them to `module.exports`

`CustomLibrary.js`

```js
'use strict';

module.exports.function1 = function() {
    console.log('function1 called');
}

module.exports.function2 = function() {
    console.log('function2 called');
}
```

Now, this won't directly execute in the browser, but you can `browserify` it into a package that can be included in HTML.

To make this, happen, you need a build script in form of a `package.json` file.

```js
{
    "name": "CustomLibrary",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "CustomLibrary.js",
    "devDependencies": {
        "browserify": "^13.0.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "browserify": "./node_modules/browserify/bin/cmd.js CustomLibrary.js --s CustomLibrary --outfile BuiltCustomLibrary.js",
        "build": "npm run browserify"
    }
}
```

To execute it, first install the `browserify` module by executing

```
$ npm install
```

Now, run

```
$ npm run build
```

This "builds" the `BuiltCustomLibrary.js` Javascript file that can be used in HTML files.

`BuiltCustomLibrary.js`

```js
(function(f){if(typeof exports==="object"&&typeof module!=="undefined"){module.exports=f()}else if(typeof define==="function"&&define.amd){define([],f)}else{var g;if(typeof window!=="undefined"){g=window}else if(typeof global!=="undefined"){g=global}else if(typeof self!=="undefined"){g=self}else{g=this}g.CustomLibrary = f()}})(function(){var define,module,exports;return (function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
'use strict';

module.exports.function1 = function() {
    console.log('function1 called');
}

module.exports.function2 = function() {
    console.log('function2 called');
}

},{}]},{},[1])(1)
});
```

Here is a HTML file for testing:

`test.html`

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="BuiltCustomLibrary.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        CustomLibrary.function1();
        CustomLibrary.function2();
    </script>
</body>
```

When you open it in your browser and open the console, you can see the printed statements.

[image: Screenshot of the console log]

Comment: Wow, that's some details!  Thank you, I'll give it a shot!